# HiddenInput not working on ASP.NET Core 2.2 Scaffolding

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

When using scaffolding in asp.net core 2.2, is there a way to make properties scaffold as Hidden Inputs?

Unfortunately `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]` does not seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)` is Ok and causes the property scaffold as hidden.

Note that after scaffolding, it doesn't generate an input of type Hidden in **your** code, instead when you run the application `<input asp-for="HiddenProperty" />` becomes `<input type="hidden" />`.

Here is a sample:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Age" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Result:**
[image: Hidden input]

Comment: Thank you... Guess I should have ran the code instead of assuming it didn't work when it scaffolded the same as the other inputs..